# Am I allowed to reimplement the Go programming language?

Tags: software

From "http://golang.org/PATENTS":

> Additional IP Rights Grant (Patents)
>
> "This implementation" means the copyrightable works distributed by
>   Google as part of the Go project.
>
> Google hereby grants to You a perpetual, worldwide, non-exclusive,
>   no-charge, royalty-free, irrevocable (except as stated in this
>   section) patent license to make, have made, use, offer to sell, sell,
>   import, transfer and otherwise run, modify and propagate the contents
>   of this implementation of Go, where such license applies only to those
>   patent claims, both currently owned or controlled by Google and
>   acquired in the future, licensable by Google that are necessarily
>   infringed by this implementation of Go. This grant does not include
>   claims that would be infringed only as a consequence of further
>   modification of this implementation. If you or your agent or exclusive
>   licensee institute or order or agree to the institution of patent
>   litigation against any entity (including a cross-claim or counterclaim
>   in a lawsuit) alleging that this implementation of Go or any code
>   incorporated within this implementation of Go constitutes direct or
>   contributory patentinfringement, or inducement of patent infringement,
>   then any patent rights granted to you under this License for this
>   implementation of Go shall terminate as of the date such litigation is
>   filed.

Are you allowed to reimplement the Go programming language by Google under this license?

Answer (score 3):

As a layman, I read the document to grant rights to modify (and etc.) **this implementation**. I don't see this document as saying anything about anything that isn't this implementation.

Comment: I asked this question on the golang mailing list and they says this isn't a problem at all (since there is no such patent, the grant is to alleviate anxiety of companies).

Comment: @LinuxDistance - If the people making that statement are employees of Google, then the fact that they are making that statement can be used as a legal defence if (hypothetically) Google sued over (hypothetical) patents related to Go.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely going to depend on exactly what you want to reimplement and how.

Assuming you're going to attempt a 'clean room' implementation of the language using only the API documentation, the most notable recent example actually comes from Google themselves when they reimplemented the Java APIs for Android/Dalvik: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_v._Google